# angularjs material responsive columns

Tags: angularjs

проблема сделать коллонки адаптивные по аналогу bootstrap 3 - например чтобы классы были как col-xs-12 col-md-5 col-lg-3, но вот с материал один класс перебивает все

```
<div layout="row" layout-xs="column" layout-wrap>
  <div class="sp__col" flex-gt-xs="100" flex-gt-sm="50" flex-gt-lg="25"></div>
  <div class="sp__col" flex-gt-xs="100" flex-gt-sm="50" flex-gt-lg="25"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

решил эту проблему вот таким способом

```
<div class="sp__col" flex-xs="100" flex-sm="50" flex-md="33" flex-lg="25"></div>
```